# PHP/Apache crash when PHP call COM objects

Tags: php, com

I am working on calling COM object method from my PHP application, but often Apache/PHP CLI crashes when I launch the script.

This one for example

```
$domainObject = new COM("Excel.application"); 
foreach ($domainObject as $obj) 
{ 
   echo $obj->Name . "<br />"; 
}
```

or this one

```
$o=new COM("NeoScope2InterOpCOM.NeoScope2InterOp"); 
$o->StartConnection(FALSE);
$o->SaisieEvent(); //SaisieEvent is a method from the COM object
```

How to handle this? There are errors for sure is my calls, but it is a bit hard to understand and fix if it crash each time.

Thanks
Cédric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fault of Xdebug : without it I have clean errors.